# Shortcut for checking boolean false value

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

In java the following works:

`boolean varBoo = true;`

`if(varBoo)`  means:  `if(varBoo = true)` and

`if(!varBoo)`  means:  `if(varBoo = false)`

Im working on a postgreSQL statement right now, which looks like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN varInt < XX AND varBoo THEN 1.0    -- Short for varBoo = TRUE
  WHEN varInt < XX AND varBoo = FALSE THEN 0.5
END
```

Is there any way to write `varBoo = FALSE` shorter in PostgreSQL?

java equivalent would be `!varBoo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `not`:

```
case
  when varInt < XX and varBoo then 1.0  
  when varInt < XX and not(varBoo) then 0.5
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's neater (to me) already.
thanks for the edit too